# Sqoop with oozie printing lastvalue to new line

Tags: sqoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

Below is my sqoop command in oozie.

```
<action name="sqoop_test" retry-max="${maxretry}" retry-interval="${retryinterval}">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://sql01.sboxdc.com/mydb --username usr1 --password ******** --table source_table --incremental lastmodified -check-column last_modified --merge-key Id --last-value "${wf:actionData('get_last_modified_time')['last_modified_date']}" --target-dir /warehouse/external_data/sms/target_location --as-textfile </command>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Above action fails as it break the last value to new line.

from logs:

```
Sqoop command arguments :
         import
         --connect
         jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://sql01.sboxdc.com/mydb
         --username
         usr1
         --password
         ********
         --table
         source_table
         --incremental
         lastmodified
         -check-column
         last_modified
         --merge-key
         Id
         --last-value
         "2019-01-01
         00:00:00"
         --target-dir
         /warehouse/external_data/sms/target_location
         --as-textfile


2019-06-18 11:19:25,768 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
2019-06-18 11:19:25,768 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 00:00:00"
2019-06-18 11:19:25,768 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
2019-06-18 11:19:25,768 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /warehouse/external_data/sms/sb_subscribermacs
2019-06-18 11:19:25,768 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --as-textfile
```

How can I force the sqoop to fit 'last_value' value in single line?

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, when you use the command element, Oozie will split the command on every space into multiple arguments. If there are spaces in an argument, like the date for your last value, you should use multiple `arg` options instead. So it would be something like:

```xml
<action name="sqoop_test" retry-max="${maxretry}" retry-interval="${retryinterval}">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <arg>import</arg>
        <arg>--conect</arg>
        <arg>jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://sql01.sboxdc.com/mydb</arg>
        <!--All the other arguments...-->
        <arg>--last-value</arg>
        <arg>"${wf:actionData('get_last_modified_time')['last_modified_date']}</arg>
        <!--Other arguments...-->        
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Comment: The next version of Oozie will support a better way to split Sqoop command lines: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2949